# How to check if a file is being referenced by other code in my application?

Tags: asp.net, resharper

I am working on an application that was written by developers before me and the application has not been well maintained to say the least. It looks as if there are files that have been added to the solution but were never used. I'm not sure as to why but that seems to be the case.

**Question:**
What is the best way to determine if a file is being referenced/used in any way in the software so that I can remove it if it is not needed? Is this something Resharper can do?

I would also like to mention that this application is very large and I would like to find a solution that could analyze the entire application versus one file at a time.

Comment: Use code lense in visual studio.

Comment: I've never used codelens before. Could you explain how to use this tool to accomplish what I'm after? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper can help you here with a feature that is called [Solution-wide Analysis](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Analysis__Enabling_Solution-Wide_Analysis.html). After enabling it (double-click the indicator circle in the bottom-right corner of the status bar), and allowing it some time to analyze all the files in your solution, it will tell you about various `public` classes that are not being used from anywhere inside the solution.

You can then use the various tools in ReSharper to find similar unused classes and methods, and make a **judgement call** whether to remove them.

Two things to note here: ReSharper (and tools like it) is a static analysis tool - it can only work based on the information it sees. It will not tell you, for example, if a piece of code is being called dynamically via reflection. So, again, make sure to have backup (and/or good source control, such as git), before doing any large removal. The second thing to note is that ReSharper's solution-wide analysis will also pick up errors in unrelated files (such as css/html), you can ignore those.

Lastly, remember that ReSharper works per-solution: if those classes used from other solutions, ReSharper will not be able to tell you about it. So again, exercise caution when removing dead code.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I ussualy do things like CTRL+SHIFT+F in visual studio which is search , and than look for filename string in entire solution.

**But it wont give you 100% ensurance** to determine if file is used or not. because if filename is generated dinamicly, retrived from source like database or service, just entire solution search will gave you false positive.

So if you assume that, those files are referanced only staticly, than you can write small program that will walk entire projects directory and search substring in source code files.